# Solved: How do I access a property of an ArrayLists object of a class while looping through an ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, arraylist, properties, concatenation

**EDIT:** Solved thanks to @Selvin, I was simply missing braces.
Furthermore I switched from ArrayList to List as ArrayLists should not be used anymore.

```
sb.Append(ListToString((Element)inputList[i].elementComponents));
```

changed to

```
sb.Append(ListToString(((Element)inputList[i]).elementComponents));
```

---

**Original Question:**

I am creating a structure of Objects of the type "Element", which includes 1 parentObject property
and an ArrayList property named "elementComponents", which contains an indefinite amount of strings AND further objects of type Element (and each of those can contain another ArrayList with strings AND objects of type Element).

The function I am trying to create is supposed to loop through a rootObjects elementsComponents-ArrayList and put all strings within itself AND within all Element's elementComponents inside of it into one big string (or StringBuilder)

Element-Class:

```
public class Element
{
/// <summary>
/// Parent-Element that this Element is directly inside of
/// </summary>
public Element? parentElement { get; set; } // irrelevant for my  question
/// <summary>
/// List of Strings AND/OR Elements in this Element
/// </summary>
public ArrayList elementComponents { get; set; } = new ArrayList();
}
```

Let's say I have an Element similar to this:

```
Element rootObj
--> (Element) parentElement = null;
--> (ArrayList) elementComponents 
----> string "OutterTest1 "
----> Element innerObj
------> parentElement = rootObj
------> elementComponents
--------> string "InnerTest1 "
--------> string "InnerTest2 "
----> string "OutterTest2 "
```

With this, ListToString(rootObj.elementComponents) would be supposed to return the following StringBuilder:
"OutterTest1 InnerTest1 InnerTest2 OuterTest2 "

What I've come up with, but it doesn't work so far:

`ListToString(rootObj.elementComponents)`

```
private static StringBuilder ListToString(ArrayList inputList)
{
// Concatenate all Strings of an ArrayList, and all strings of lists contained in the list into one big string.

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i++)
{
if (inputList[i].GetType() == typeof(Element))
{
sb.Append(ListToString((Element)inputList[i].elementComponents)); // does not work like that
}
else // otherwise it can only ever be a string
sb.Append(inputList[i].ToString());
}
return sb;
}
```

I have been trying to find ways to access an ArrayList's object at index i's properties within a for-loop (so the  elementComponents-property of the object within the ArrayList at Index i, which is of type Element) to continue looping through that next, but I haven't found a way to do so.

Help would be greatly appreciated, newbie here.
Thanks!

Comment: Why `ArrayList` instead of `List<object>` ?

Comment: you may use pattern matching with types and switch statment (feel free to do internet search over this topic)

Comment: *does not work like that* you are missing braces `(Element)inputList[i].elementComponents` will try to get `elementComponents` of `object` (which doesnt compile) and then cast it to `Element` and you need to cast `inputList[i]` to `Element` and then get field

Comment: @Selvin Wouldn't the result be roughly the same using List<object>?

Comment: *We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development.* - MS official docs ...

Comment: @Selvin "you are missing braces"
I can't believe I didn't get that, nor that the exception didn't tell me this.
Fixed that, now it compiles and works :)
Also simply switched to List<object> without hassle.

Now that was an easy fix, thanks a lot.
Sometimes it's easy to miss little things...

I don't think I can mark your answer as correct in a comment like this, can I?